# Is there a notion of a complex/analytic diffeological space?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, analytic-geometry, generalized-smooth-spaces, diffeology

I have a bit of a general question. This seems like something you can do, but I can't seem to find much reference for this.. Perhaps something like this already exists in a different guise. But, is there an concept of a complex diffeology analogous to a smooth one?

That is: plots should be defined in terms of maps from open subsets $U \subset \mathbb{C}^{n}$. Axioms concerning compatibility of plots should be defined in terms of analytic maps between $U$ and $V$..etc.

Perhaps there should be extra conditions, or a modification of the conditions, but essentially I'm asking about the existence of a sort of space described by a sheaf on the site of open subsets of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, or maybe they should be Stein.. If anybody could point me in the direction of anything that may seem relevant, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have realized that you can (I think!) endow a smooth diffeological space with a "complex/holomorphic structure". It should go something like this:

If $\mathfrak{X}$ is a diffeological space, defined via a collection of plots $ U \rightarrow \mathfrak{X}$, then we can define a complex structure on $\mathfrak{X}$ if there exists a subcollection of plots (perhaps called, holomorphic plots)  $ U \rightarrow \mathfrak{X}$ such that:

- $ U \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$ for some $n \geq 0 $ ( and hence $U$ has an induced complex structure )
- If $U$ and $V$ are complex domains, then the composition $ V \rightarrow U \rightarrow \mathfrak{X}$ is a *holomorphic plot* of $\mathfrak{X}$ if $V \rightarrow U$ is a holomorphic map.

Note that if $V \rightarrow U$ is a holomorphic map, then the composition $V \rightarrow U \rightarrow \mathfrak{X}$ is a (smooth) plot. But it is not guaranteed to be contained in our subcollection of holomorphic plots.

Then, you can also define morphisms of complex diffeological spaces $\mathfrak{X}$, $\mathfrak{Y}$ (i.e. diffeological spaces with complex structures) to be morphisms of diffeological spaces $\mathfrak{X} \rightarrow \mathfrak{Y}$ that is compatible with the choices of holomorphic plots. That is, if $U \rightarrow \mathfrak{X}$ is a holomorphic plot, then $  U \rightarrow \mathfrak{X} \rightarrow \mathfrak{Y}$ should also be a holomorphic plot.

I believe that this is sound, and you can embed complex manifolds into diffeologies with complex structure this way. However, if this is indeed sound, I wonder what the relationship would be if you started off by defining a concrete sheaf on the concrete site of open domains in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ (or Stein manifolds..etc), as in Enxin Wu's thesis linked in ARA's comment below.

Comment: As far as I know, such concepts exist in the literature, (e.g. see Remark 1.2.9 and the paragraph after that in Wu's Thesis https://ir.lib.uwo.ca/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1903&context=etd). However, it seems they have not been studied thoroughly in detail at all.

Comment: thanks for your comment! interesting.. that's probably exactly what I'm wondering about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer the question posed in the last paragraph.

There is a canonical forgetful functor from the site of open subsets of ${\bf C}^n$ and holomorphic maps to the site of open subsets of ${\bf R}^n$ and smooth maps.

This forgetful functor induces a canonical cocontinuous forgetful functor $F$ from holomorphic spaces to diffeological spaces.

Now a complex structure on a diffeological space $\def\fX{{\frak X}}\fX$ can be identified with the data of a holomorphic space $\def\fH{{\frak H}}\fH$ together with an isomorphism $F(\fH)→\fX$.
The plots of $\fH$ get mapped to the holomorphic plots of $\fX$ under this isomorphism.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the general solution to your question can be found in "A theory of plots" by Atsushi Yamaguchi [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DJ4ICgDQmGj7so5a_UXInNkfsvJI4uhN/view)? Slides from his talk at the last conference on diffeology and differential homotopy are [here](https://diffeology.net/index.php/special-event/).